# What is the T(s) equation for this function?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

***What is the exact running time for this function?***

and I'm a CS student, so I want some resources to help calculate T(s), but really I do need help in this code.

```
int function(int arr[], int s)
{
    // arr is array of size s
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j <= s; j++)
        {
            int sum= 0;

            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
                a+= arr[k];

            m= max(a, m);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `n` is not a variable in this procedure, the `T(n) = 1`

Assuming, that you are actually looking for `T(s)` let's count it together:

We have the outer-most loop (I), the inner-most loop (III) and the middle loop (II) and T_I(s) is what we are looking for:

```
T_III(i,j) = j-i+1
 T_II(i,s) = sum(T_III(i, j) for j in [i, s])
    T_I(s) = sum(T_II(i, s) for i in [1, s])
```

The `T_I(s)` can be further expanded into:

[image]

To expand the sums, I used the formula for summing consecutive numbers in an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: First of all, thank you and yes forgive me I do mean T(s), but I still didn't get how the equation will look like, like how I will end writing all summations together?

Comment: @user13313695 how about now? If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted and leave an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate that man, can you give me please some resources to study these things?

Comment: Well, the topic is quite complex. It's usually covered during discreet maths courses. You can try the following cheatsheet as a starter https://www.easycalculation.com/learn-sum-of-series.php